# Перебор значений массива с отрицательным приращением

Tags: java, комбинаторика

Есть массив, например :

```
int array[] = new int[100];
array = {25,25,25,25...};
```

нужно перебрать все уникальные значения, то есть -   {...25,25,24};{...25,25,23};
Полным перебором очень долго получается...

Comment: можете на маленьком массиве показать, что хотите получить, просто из того примера что в описании не совсем понятно.

Comment: например: [2,2,2], [2,2,1], [2,2,0], [2,1,1], [2,1,0], [1,1,1], [1,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]

Comment: не силен в алгоритмах,  но думаю чтобы получить всевозможные комбинации нужно просто перебрать всевозможные комбинации. Для ускорения могу посоветовать распараллелить данный процесс.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что в случае  с вашим массивом у вас ровно *25^100* или ~2^465 вариантов? Это существенно больше, чем можно выразить любой переменной. Если вы будете перебирать по 25^10 вариантов в секунду, на полный перебор уйдет 2*10^118 лет. Напомню, вселенная существует ~14*10^9 лет.